# discord.js how can i send an embed and text at the same time?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I saw a stack overflow post explaining it but when I tried that answer it doesn't work it just sends the @everyone with no embed after it. The embed works if it's on its own tho, anyone who might know how to fix this please help me. Thank you!

```
let Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#FF0000')
            .setTitle(event.name + " (Starting Now)")
            .setDescription(getFormatDescription(event.format) + "\n" + event.date + " @ " + event.time)
            .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/UmwJYKP.png')
            .setFooter('Dont miss out!', 'https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/shivaxis-rlcraft/images/e/ea/Diamond.png/revision/latest?cb=20210527212751');
        client.channels.cache.get('890259780436914196').send('@everyone', { embeds: [Embed] }).then(message => {
            message.crosspost();
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried with content?

```js
.send({content: "@everyone", embeds: [Embed]})
```

Comment: That worked thank you very much!